# Click event not work in pyqt5 with Qlabels

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to define a click event for this class but no error is given and the code does not work properly.
In this class, I want to design a button that the user can click to call a function and perform a specific operation.

I want to run a method by clicking.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
class memuActions(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self,title,parent,width,height,src):
        QLabel.__init__(self, title ,parent=parent)
        self.cont=QLabel(parent)
        self.cont.resize(width,height)
        self.cont.setObjectName("cont")
        self.cont.setStyleSheet("#cont::hover{background-color:#EBEBEB;}")
        
        self.ico=QLabel(self.cont)
        self.ico.resize(self.cont.width(),40)
        self.ico.setPixmap(QPixmap(src))
        self.ico.setScaledContents(True)

        self.ds=QLabel(title,self.cont)
        self.ds.setWordWrap(True)
        self.ds.resize(self.cont.width(),25)
        self.ds.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.ds.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.ds.move(2,self.ico.height()+2)

    def move(self,x,y):
        self.cont.move(x,y)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

        
class main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(800,600)

        af=memuActions("ASD",self,60,60,"aa.png")
        af.move(100,50)
        af.clicked.connect(self.a)


    def a(self):
        print("PL")

app=QApplication([])
win=main()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the code does not work properly"? Are you adding a `memuActions` instance to a layout or are you just showing it?

Comment: Yes, I added, but the click event of this class does not work and gives an error

Comment: *What* error? Please be more clear and specific, read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: I put the full code of this question

Comment: You are still not telling us what error you got. The above code doesn't give any error at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various problems with your code, with the most important being a general misunderstanding of the parent/child relation.

The `memuActions` instance is created with the window as parent, but `self.cont` is created with the *same* window as parent, so `self.count` and all its children will be child of the window, not of `memuActions`.

Another problem is related to the fact that you're not using [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), which will result in leaving the widget with the default size: all widgets created with a parent have a default size of 100x30.

Since you're creating all other widgets with the wrong parent, they are actually covering your `menuActions` widget, so it will never get a proper mouse click event.

If you want to create a custom widget with fixed geometries, and you don't add that widget to a layout, you *must* manually set its size, either by `resize()` or with `setMinimumSize()`. Since your widget is composed of many children, you must use [`childrenRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#childrenRect-prop) to find the final size, which is a composite of all geometries of the children.

Then, the `cont` widget is covered by the pixmap label, it will never receive hover events. In order to avoid so, you must make the label transparent to mouse events, so that the widgets *under* it will receive them.

Finally, consider that Qt discourages using direct children of a main window, as you should *always* use a [central widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework):

> **Note:** Creating a main window without a central widget is not supported. You must have a central widget even if it is just a placeholder.

You should anyway use a layout manager for that central widget, otherwise resizing the window might partially (or completely) hide its contents.

In any case, here's a corrected and working version of your code.

```
class memuActions(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, title, parent, width, height, src):
        QLabel.__init__(self, title, parent=parent)
        self.cont = QLabel(self)
        self.cont.resize(width, height)
        self.cont.setObjectName("cont")
        self.cont.setStyleSheet("#cont::hover{ background-color:#EBEBEB; }")
        
        self.ico = QLabel(self)
        self.ico.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)
        self.ico.resize(width, 40)
        self.ico.setPixmap(QPixmap(src))
        self.ico.setScaledContents(True)

        self.ds = QLabel(title, self)
        self.ds.setWordWrap(True)
        self.ds.resize(width, 25)
        self.ds.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.ds.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.ds.move(2, self.ico.height() + 2)

        self.resize(self.childrenRect().size())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()
```

<sup>Note:</sup>
<sup>1. class (and constants) should *always* use capitalized names, so you should call your classes `MemuActions` and `Main`;</sup>
<sup>2. please use spaces, avoiding them won't make any difference in performance or memory, and it only makes your code *terrible* and very annoying to read; read more about this and other *very important* aspects on the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (aka, PEP-8).</sup>